# Failed to run a background application in elastic beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASP.Net core web application which I am publishing to AWS using Elastic beanstalk.

The requirement is, I have to run another C++ application (app.exe), on click of a button in Home page. The C++ application will do all the background processing.

So, I attached my app.exe and it's dependencies to web application, and copying them as part of the build.

On clicking the elastic beanstalk weblink, I can see my Home page with the button to run the application. But when I click the button, my app.exe is not running.

Below is the error I can see in elastic beanstalk logs

```
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000006e77e
Faulting process id: 0x1b98
Faulting application start time: 0x01d840589d9b287d
Faulting application path: C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\test\app.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
```

To dig furthur, I enabled the RDP on elastic beanstalk instance and connected to it .If run the application (app.exe) from command prompt, it is running fine.

As per another threads suggestion, also set `Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true` still the same.

Any suggestion please..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to find the answer, thinking issue is related running an application from unsecured network, so enabled HTTPS on port 443, also created SSL certificate using OpenSSL, and imported to AWS Certificate Manager which is added to Elastic beanstalk load balancer. But still ended with the same.

Finally, came to know that, my background application(app.exe) I am running doesn't have permissions to save the files downloading from S3 to the folder it is running from. Once I redirected the files location to a manually created folder as part of .ebextensions, it's solved.